# using UIPopoverController with UItextFiled

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I have this code when I click on my `UITexField`, I show my `UIPopover` and I get the value selected,but my problem how I can use other `textField` with `UIPopover` in other xib ,can i have many `UIViewController` to recieve the selected value?`-

```
(IBAction) btnShowLan:(id) sender {

    choix=1;
    if (self.popoverControllerl == nil) {
        MyPopOverView *movies = [[MyPopOverView alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyPopOverView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]; 
        movies.listOfMovies = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        movies.listOfMovies=mutable3;
        movies.choix=1;

        UIPopoverController *popover =[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:movies]; 

        popover.delegate = self;
        [movies release];

        self.popoverControllerl = popover;
        [popover release];
    }

    CGRect popoverRect = [self.view convertRect:[langue frame] 
                                       fromView:[langue superview]];

    popoverRect.size.width = 20; 
    popoverRect.size.height =20;
    [self.popoverControllerl presentPopoverFromRect:popoverRect 
                                            inView:self.view 
                          permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny 
                                          animated:YES];
}
```

//////////////////////
this code used to recive detailItem

```
XMLTestAppDelegate   *appDelegates = (authe*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        appDelegates.viewController.detailItem =[listOfMovies objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

`

Comment: haw i can use the appdelegate with other xib?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking is basically "if I have a textfield with a value in it in a popover and the value changes, how do I tell other parts of my application that the value has changed."

While there might be a lot of ways of doing it, here are a couple possibilities.

1.) Create a singleton class to store all of your shared value. When the popover changes the value, change that value in the singleton and have all the other observers using that value ask the singleton for its value.

2.) Use an NSNotification and store the chang value in the notifications "userinfo" and subscribe the other classes to the notification...have the popover dispatch an event changed whenenver this changes.

3.) use core data to stor and change the value in shared data